# PowerShell Get-ChildItem with An Array Of Wildcard strings

Tags: powershell, wildcard

I have a folder with a bunch of SQL Server .BAK files of several databases. The .BAK file names keep changing every day.

Of those, I'm only interested in 3-4 databases' **latest** BAK files for `Restore-SqlDatabase`.

This is what I have so far:

```
$databases = @('Orders', 'Items', 'Returns')
$BackupPath  = '\\BACKUPSERVER\BackupData\'
$latestBackupFile = Get-ChildItem $BackupPath -Attributes !Directory *$databases[0]* | Sort-Object -Descending -Property LastWriteTime | Select-Object -First 1
$latestBackupFile
#Restore-SqlDatabase -ServerInstance "my-vm" -Database "Orders" -BackupFile "\\BACKUPSERVER\BackupData\AODA2.Orders.2024-01-15.22-23-13.BAK" -ReplaceDatabase
#Restore-SqlDatabase -ServerInstance "my-vm" -Database "Items" -BackupFile "\\BACKUPSERVER\BackupData\MMMWW.Items.2024-01-15.22-23-13.BAK" -ReplaceDatabase
```

The `Restore-SqlDatabase` command is working when executed by itself; I've included in the above script for context.

`*$databases[0]*` - This doesn't result in a wild card string  like `*Orders*` as I hoped for.

I'm not sure how to craft a ForEach loop for
a) looping through the `$databases` array to get the wild card string like `*Orders*`, `*Items*`, `*Returns*` etc
and
b) looping through the latest .BAK file for each of those wild cards to construct the `Restore-SqlDatabase` command.

I'm new to PowerShell; How to do this? Thank you.

Comment: Clarification, please: You want to look at the latest `*Orders*`, `*Items*`, and `*Returns*`, and restore each of them?

Comment: @JeffZeitlin - yes correct. That's exactly what I'm trying to accomplish. There may be other databases in future, so I thought putting them in an array like that would help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PowerShell has two distinct grammars, described in the documentation as ["parsing modes"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_parsing?view=powershell-7.4):

- Argument mode:

  - applies to everything immediately following a command name, including your `*$database[0]*` argument
- Expression mode:

  - applies to mostly everything else, and works exactly as you expect: `$databases[0]` would be interpreted as an array index operation

When PowerShell encounters a so-called "bareword token" in argument mode, it automatically interprets it as the contents of an expandable string literal expression.

In other words, the argument `*$databases[0]*` is interpreted the same as if you'd written `"*$databases[0]*"`.

In an expandable string literal, only *simple variable expressions* are recognized and expanded - so PowerShell tries to evaluate `$databases` on its own without considering `[0]`.

You can escape the string interpolation rules by wrapping the expression with the subexpression operator `$()`:

```
"*$($databases[0])*"
```

It's good to know, *but you don't really need it here* - you need a loop!

> I'm not sure how to craft a ForEach loop

The [`foreach` loop statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_foreach?view=powershell-7.4) in PowerShell is fairly straightforward:

```
foreach ($item in $collection) {
  # work with each $item here
}
```

Let's try that with your `$databases` array:

```
foreach ($databaseName in $databases) {
  # find the latest backup file containing the db name in its file name
  $latestBackupFile = Get-ChildItem $BackupPath -File -Filter "*$databaseName*.bak" | Sort-Object -Descending -Property LastWriteTime | Select-Object -First 1

  if ($latestBackupFile) {
    Restore-SqlDatabase -ServerInstance "my-vm" -Database $databaseName -BackupFile $latestBackupFile.FullName -ReplaceDatabase
  }
  else {
    Write-Warning "Unable to locate backup file for database $databaseName"
  }
}
```

Since we're no longer relying on an array indexer, `$databaseName` can now be expanded in the filter string as expected - on the first iteration the `$databaseName` variable will have the value `"Orders"`, so the argument expression `-Filter "*$databaseName*.bak"` will result in the filter string `*Orders*.bak`

Lastly, if you need to pad the database name with characters that might otherwise be interpreted as part of the variable path, you can qualify the variable path with `{}`:

```
# underscore _ below would have been interpreted as part of the variable path expression `$databaseName_` if not for the curly brackets
... -Filter "*${databaseName}_*.bak"
```

Comment: Yeah, this is where I was expecting to go... Your explanations are generally more thorough than mine; thanks.

Comment: That was at least 2 hours worth of PowerShell learning in that one answer. Thank you for the detailed explanation.

Comment: How to exclude certain .BAK files in that directory? That is how to use `-Exclude` together with `-Filter`?